# Conditional unit tests

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, mstest

This seems to be a touchy subject so I'm probably just going to get a lot of hate for this one, but here goes nothing:

The application I'm working on heavily relies on an external API, and that API requires a personalized developer key in order for it to even do anything. This is making it particularly difficult for a unit testing newb like me to write tests that I can redistribute without living with the constant fear that my developer key might be compromised.

My point is this: I'd like to prevent my unit tests from running if a developer key is not provided. It should also be clear that when this occurs, it is not an application error but a user error.

Is this something I can easily do using the MSTest framework?

**What I've tried so far** (VB)

Right now I'm simply letting my tests fail if a developer key is not set:

```
<TestClass()> Public Class Tests

    Private Shared DeveloperKey As NMAKey

    <ClassInitialize>
    Public Shared Sub Initialize(context As TestContext)
        DeveloperKey = NMAKey.TryParse("Your developer key")
    End Sub

    <TestMethod>
    Public Sub Example()
        ' test condition
        Assert.IsNotNull(DeveloperKey)

        '
        ' actual test code that relies on 'DeveloperKey' being set
        '
    End Sub

End Class
```

My problem with this is that there is no distinction between user error and actual unit failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably put developer key in configuration file and ignore the file in version control. You could check if the key is found in initialization of test class instead of individual tests. Another possibilty is to write test that checks the key exists in the configuration file. I don't really understand why you consider it important to distinct between user error and application error, broken is broken :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I feel it's important to distinct between the two because there might be nothing wrong with the code, but the unit tests would still fail 100% of the time if a developer key is not provided. In this case broken is not really broken in my opinion. It's just a scenario that doesn't seem to be covered by the MSTest framework (as far as I can tell).

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer. Config files were a great idea. I also moved the test condition to the initialize method like you suggested and replaced `Assert.IsNotNull` with `Assert.Inconclusive` to make the distinction. So far this seems to work fantastic, and I don't need to write the test condition in every procedure.